# JavaScript Isotope Gallery - two active tabs?

Tags: javascript, jquery-isotope

I am trying to load two Isotope galleries on my website (two separate pages) but only have one JavaScript function running the gallery.

The first gallery is working fine but the second one does not show anything until one of the tabs is clicked.

Here is my code:

```
$(function() {
    var filterList = {
        init: function() {
            $('#portfoliolist').mixItUp({
                selectors: {
                    target: '.portfolio',
                    filter: '.filter'
                },

                load: {
                    filter: '.shute',
                    filter: '.jab'
                }
            });
        }
    };

    filterList.init()
});
```

The second gallery is filter: '.jab', why won't this load on default when the .shute one does?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you define the same property twice in the `load` object?

Comment: I'm novice with JavaScript and thought this was easiest way to load two Isotope galleries?

Comment: By defining the same property twice, you are effectively overwriting the first definition.

Comment: So how do I define a new property and not effect the first one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `filter: $('.shute, .jab')` instead of defining `filter` twice.

**Code:**

```js
$('#portfoliolist').mixItUp({
  selectors: {
    target: '.portfolio',
    filter: '.filter'
  },

  load: {
    filter: $('.shute, .jab')
  }
});
```

Comment: This reverts the problem. .shute now does not load and .jab does?

Comment: Check out my edit @AshyC. Try passing a `jQuery` object instead of a string.